# Finding hash marks (#) using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I'm using perl regular expressions to parse a musical chord name, such as `E#m`. I can't seem to get perl to recognize the `#`. It also won't work when stored in a string, despite the fact that other characters work fine from the string. I have also tried escaping it with a backslash.

To reiterate:

```
my ($scale, $mod, $chord)  = /\b([a-g])(\#|b|)\b/i ;
```

or

```
my $sharp = "#";
my ($scale, $mod, $chord)  = /\b([a-g])($sharp|b|)\b/i ;
```

don't work, but

```
my $sharp = "n";
my ($scale, $mod, $chord)  = /\b([a-g])($sharp|b|)\b/i ;
```

detects `n`

Comment: Remove the ending word boundary and use it inside the group. `\b([a-g])(#|b\b)`

Comment: my ($scale, $mod) = /([a-g]+)([${sharp}b]*)/i;

Answer (score 1):

```
\b([a-g])(\#|b|)\b

                ^^
```

Your `\b` at the end is the culprit.After matching `a#` it looks for `\b` which is not there as `\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`.So `\b` cannot be found (because `#` is not a part of `\w` so `$` after `#` is not a `word boundary`) and it fails.Remove the last `\b` and it works.Or

use

```
\b([a-g])(#|b\b)
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/39

`n` was getting matched as `n$` forms a word boundary and so `\b` was getting a match.

Answer (score 1):

This is from http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html.

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> 1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is
>      a word character.
> 2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> 3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character
>      and the other is not a word character.

Basically, a # sign is not a word character.

Wihout knowing what your data looks like, the following is only a guess:

```
([a-gA-G])([#b])(m)?
```